# Searching for HLA-B in DNA results

Tags: gene, genome, igv

I'm trying to find the HLA-B*15:01 variant in my DNA results, prompted from this research paper: [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8142661/#:~:text=HLA%2DB*15%3A01%20is%20strongly%20associated%20with%20asymptomatic,mechanism%20underlying%20early%20viral%20clearance](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8142661/#:%7E:text=HLA%2DB*15%3A01%20is%20strongly%20associated%20with%20asymptomatic,mechanism%20underlying%20early%20viral%20clearance).

I have DNA test results from Dante Labs that contain the following files

```
"*.bam"
"*.bam.bai"
"*.cnv.vcf.gz"
"*.cnv.vcf.gz.tbi"
"*.filtered.indel.vcf.gz"
"*.filtered.indel.vcf.gz.tbi"
"*.filtered.snp.vcf.gz"
"*.filtered.snp.vcf.gz.tbi"
"*1_SA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
"*SA_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz"
```

I tried loading this on the Genome Explorer on Sequencing.com, but it couldn't find HLA-B at all, only HLA-A and HLA-C.

Then I tried loading the VCF files in IGV. I was able to filter to Chromosome 6 and HLA-B, which resolved to position

```
chr6:31,319,652-31,326,956
```

The CNV VCF says no variables found for chr6:31,319,652-31,326,956
The filtered Indel VCF did produce some variants for this position, but I have no clue how to search deeper specifically for HLA-B*15:01. Here is a screenshot: [image]

The filtered SNP VCF produced *alot* more variants for this position, but again, I don't know how to go deeper than this.

I'm not really sure what to do from here?

I don't have data on what the reference was, so that is unknown to me. I will reach out to Dante Labs about that, is there some sort of standard that is supposed to be used, or is it different for every genome provider?

How do I actually perform the check in IGV assuming the reference did not have it and the VCF did. I also assume this VCF does not have this allele, but I frankly am lost into how to confirm it to the "last mile" through the VCF so to speak, or even just go straight to BAM

Answer (score 2):

Typical SNP calling wouldn't give you good results on classical HLA genes. Ignore the VCF. Try a dedicated HLA genotyper on raw reads instead. I heard [optitype](https://github.com/FRED-2/OptiType) is a good one for exome or whole-genome data. I haven't used it myself, though.

Answer (score 1):

The specific question and the easiest question is the absence of HLA-B*15:01 from your sample and that is not unexpected at all.

The maximum frequency of this allele is 40% found in "[China Beijing pop 2](http://www.allelefrequencies.net/hla6006a.asp?page=40&hla_locus=B&hla_locus_type=Classical&hla_allele1=15&hla_allele2=&hla_selection=&hla_pop_selection=&hla_population=&hla_country=&hla_dataset=&hla_region=&hla_ethnic=&hla_study=&hla_sample_size=&hla_sample_size_pattern=equal&hla_sample_year=&hla_sample_year_pattern=equal&hla_level=&hla_level_pattern=equal&hla_show=&hla_order=order_1&standard=g)" , this however is really unusually high and was published by Guang Yang et al (2009, IJI 37, 205-212).

Mostly this allele is present at 5% for moderate frequency of occurrence for example Europe, such as in Germany [here](http://www.allelefrequencies.net/hla6006a.asp?page=40&hla_locus=B&hla_locus_type=Classical&hla_allele1=15&hla_allele2=&hla_selection=&hla_pop_selection=&hla_population=&hla_country=&hla_dataset=&hla_region=&hla_ethnic=&hla_study=&hla_sample_size=&hla_sample_size_pattern=equal&hla_sample_year=&hla_sample_year_pattern=equal&hla_level=&hla_level_pattern=equal&hla_show=&hla_order=order_1&standard=g). Moreover, in some populations the frequency is very low <<1%, e.g. India or Israel.

So a sample genome at random the will not have the B*15:01.

---

The more complicated issue is the VCF and the reference genome. This is because the basis on whether an allele is present or absent is a comparison against the reference genome which will generate the VCF. Thus understanding the HLA-B alleles of the reference genome is really important. You need a reference genome which lacks HLA-B*15:01, therefore if your VCF also lacks the allele, its missing. However, if HLA-B*15:01 is present in the reference genome your VCF will not present the allele if its present.

The probability is that the allele is missing from both the reference and sample genome.

---

**Comments**

**Easy way** The easiest way is search the IGV for [LT618832.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/LT618832.1) (HLA-B*15:01 reference), IGV has a motif finder, here https://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/motif_finder

**Hard way**
This is how I'd do it ..

- convert the bam to fasta then
- run a blast against Genbank reference LT618832.1

I'd section the bam file into the locus of interest (e.g. chromosome 6) e.g. ... `samtools view ... ChrName: ... > chromo6.bam`: you'd need to cross check how to do this last bit ... then via `samtools >1.3`,

```
samtools fasta chromosome6.bam > chromosome6.fasta
```

Finally you download a standalone version of `blast`, I assume its on `-c bioconda` ...

```
blastn -query HLAB1501.faa -db chromosome6.fa -out myhits.txt
```

From memory I don't think you need to `makeblastdb` for a fasta onto a fasta db.

You'd need to map the SNPs in introns parsing (the coordinates are in the Genbank reference), or optically against the Genbank reference onto the `blast` output.

You may want to cross check the HLA-B*15:01 against https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=HLA-B%2A15%3A01

[but be careful about the introns]

`motif_finder` seems easier and accommodates potential heterozygosity.